# Is it possible to write a FAKE build script that transfers a file (SFTP) to a remote server and runs some docker commands on that server?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

As part of my build script, I am creating a docker image and saving it as a tar. I would also like my build script to transfer that file to my application server and run some docker commands to load the image etc.
I am building on a Windows machine, and am deploying to a Linux machine (Synology). Is it possible to automate the entire deployment with FAKE?

Comment: Short answer: yes - it is possible. The question would be if you're looking for dedicated modules that do all these things or the possibility to call a shell to do some things for you. There is an old [FTP helper](https://fake.build/apidocs/v5/legacy/fake-ftphelper.html) but it is marked as obsolete. You can also always fall back to the [process API](https://fake.build/core-process.html) or write your own thing using any other .NET library.

Comment: @WalternativE seems like writing a utility and calling it with via the process API might be the easiest for me.

Comment: Possibly this would be of use to you: https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/pull/1782/commits/76801f489ea9d0d3f3cf12413c8edecb031985f9

Comment: @JimFoye it seems that the Ftp api is not yet ported over to FAKE 5. Have I got that correct?

Comment: @ChechyLevas Right, but you can just copy that FTP script I wrote and reference it from your FAKE script.

Comment: @JimFoye I did just that and almost got it work (by enabling ftp - without the s - on the server) but got some file permissions error which I need to investigate. I will report back with an update early next week when I get access the server again.